# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I add Header to GET request

Tags: javascript, php

Then I add header(access) to my GET request I recieve

> GET https://some.api.address/endpoint net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR xhr.js:210

I use axios to send requests.
Without header all work, but i cannot get data without access token.

API written on PHP.
I have set Access-Control-Allow-Headers in PHP.

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Region, Access');
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing space char, like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Region,Access');
```